# Apache Camel Custom Component Autowire Problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Having a custom component that written by myself in a Spring Boot Application. When i use autowire annotation any class will be null.

The reason, spring and camel context are different?
If it is, how can i use class without autowire or 
with ApplicationContextAware ?

Thanks..

```
@Component
@Lazy
public class ClientProducer extends DefaultProducer {

    @Autowired
    private RequestContext requestContext;
    @Autowired
    private XXXConfigProperties xxxConfigProperties ;
```

Comment: Have you read this: https://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i have already.. Thanks..

Comment: How do you configure the producer?

Comment: In a custom CamelContextConfiguration class, 
I added the component in beforeApplicationStart method. Do you mean this?

Comment: Btw, maybe inialize producer will be a problem. I have already tested it. Nothing happened..

Comment: No you use the producer in a route. How does this code look like? Do you have assigned a endpoint URI?

Comment: i just call the endpoint with ProducerTemplate. @Autowided ProducerTemplate send(thecomponenturi,exchange)

Comment: You only show one piece of a custom component. You need to use spring ioc to create that class from the camel component in its create producer method. To do that use injector from camel context that will use spring ioc under the hood

Comment: omg,you're the inspiration! Many thanks. I did it! :)) @ClausIbsen